# Specifying path for the target in Makefile

Tags: makefile

So here is a very simple Makefile. I can't seem to specify the final location of the targets... I want the message.o and main.o to be located in the build directory. However, when I try to use the following code they end up in the Makefile directory. When the compiler tries to create the final executable it spits out an error because it is looking for the .o files in the ./build/ directory. I'm pretty sure there is some flaw in my understanding of makefiles, but other examples in the net shows similar solutions. Thanks in advance.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
SOURCE = ./src/
BUILD = ./build/


output: $(BUILD)main.o $(BUILD)message.o
        gcc $^ -o output

$(BUILD)main.o: $(SOURCE)main.c
        gcc -c $^

$(BUILD)message.o: $(SOURCE)message.c
        gcc -c $^
```

Comment: You forgot `-o $@` in your compilation recipes. `gcc`created the object files in the current directory, not in `$(BUILD)`.

Comment: Just to note, this doesn't have anything to do with make or makefiles per se.  Make is just a tool for running commands in a specific order.  You have to provide the commands for it to run and if you give the wrong command then things won't work, just like if you typed those wrong commands into your shell prompt instead of using a makefile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to speficy the output path of the object files or else your files `main.o` and `message.o` will not be generated in the `build` folder but in the current directory.
Please see below example :

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
SOURCE = ./src/
BUILD = ./build/

output: $(BUILD)main.o $(BUILD)message.o
    gcc $^ -o output

$(BUILD)main.o: $(SOURCE)main.c
    gcc -c $^ -o $@

$(BUILD)message.o: $(SOURCE)message.c
    gcc -c $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Yes! Works like  a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @RoKsPy is this works for you then request to accept the answer